# Wildcard App ID for pairing app with external hardware

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

This was asked quite a while ago in SO but there isn't a definitive answer. Can we use wildcard App ID (eq: ABCDEFGH.com.company.*) to pair app/s to an external hardware? Or does it have to be an explicit App ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got ahold of a tech guy from the hardware manufacturer who knows what he's talking about. He confirmed that wildcard ID is okay! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think wildcard App IDs will work fine.
[Check here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1713/_index.html ] - Apple's Tech Q&A on this

Comment: I don't see any mention of external hardware on that page

Comment: [This site](http://iphone.gumbypp.com/provisioning.html) says no, but I cannot find any other references to confirm.